# How to change map marker color on each layer using Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I am trying to change map markers colors on each layer from an answer I received previously. The following code creates the different layers with all the map markers being the same color. I have 3 png files locally consisting of red, blue an green map marker images.

```
// create groups to add the markers
var solarGroup = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
var hydroGroup = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
var windGroup = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);

// use the L.geoJSON to convert the geojson into layers
L.geoJSON(json,{
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    // create a marker and add them to the correct group
    if(feature.properties.primary_fuel === "Solar"){
        L.marker(layer.getLatLng())
          .bindPopup("<h2>" + feature.properties.name + "<h2> <hr> <h3>Primary Fuel " + feature.properties.primary_fuel + "</h3>")
          .addTo(solarGroup);
    }else if(feature.properties.primary_fuel === "Hydro"){
        L.marker(layer.getLatLng(), {icon: myIcon})
          .bindPopup("<h2>" + feature.properties.name + "<h2> <hr> <h3>Primary Fuel " + feature.properties.primary_fuel + "</h3>")
          .addTo(hydroGroup);
    } else if(feature.properties.primary_fuel === "Wind"){
        L.marker(layer.getLatLng())
          .bindPopup("<h2>" + feature.properties.name + "<h2> <hr> <h3>Primary Fuel " + feature.properties.primary_fuel + "</h3>")
          .addTo(windGroup);
    }
  }
})

// create Layer Control
var overlayMaps = {
    "Solar": solarGroup,
    "Hydro": hydroGroup,
    "Wind": windGroup
}
L.control.layers(null, overlayMaps).addTo(map);
```

I have tried adding this for hydro...

```
var myIcon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: 'static/images/blue.png',
  iconSize: [38, 95],
  iconAnchor: [22, 94],
  popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  shadowUrl: 'my-icon-shadow.png',
  shadowSize: [68, 95],
  shadowAnchor: [22, 94]
});
```

Comment: There does not seem to be anything particularly wrong in the code you show. What does your blue icon look like? Are the popup contents correctly filled? Are your 3 different layers populated accordingly with your data?

Comment: I get the map, but with the unloaded image icon as map markers

Comment: Ah that is a more specific issue then. A screenshot would be nice, but above all sharing your project file structure would be necessary. Are you using any framework or build engine?

Comment: It was a finding the image problem, I fixed it by using  ../static/images/file.png

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is answered in the comments and it is a specific user question, this can't answered better by a other user then the OP self.